# 'Runner' Game, loop sliding background, remove children when outside

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I've just started using actionscript 3 and I am currently trying to make a scrolling runner game in Flash CS5, similar to the Flood Runner games from Tremor games. The difference is, however, that my game *is not an endless* runner game and the character has a destination that she must reach before time runs out. Alot of the tutorials I've read on the subject use the player character's x and y positions to scroll, but in my game the background scrolls independent of the character. The tutorials I've read about this do not address my problems specifically.

TL;DR: I do not want to loop my background but have a series of multiple background images.

I am trying to figure out the best way to patch together multiple background images seamlessly. Currently, I have one background movie clip object at the maximum pixel width. The background object scrolls to the left independently of the position of the player character, who can only jump.

What I am thinking about doing is this:

Every time a point at the far right edge of one background image reaches the far right stage boundary, I have my actionscript call an addChild command for the next background object and instantiate it at the far right stage boundary. It will scroll at the same speed as the preceding background object.

I also need to figure out how to remove the background objects once they have completely exited the stage for memory purposes.

So, what would be the best way to tackle this?

Comment: Hi, have you already tried to code the solution you talk about? What specific point do you need help on?

Comment: I tried coding the solution but I was having some trouble working with the point variable for the far left of the first background object and having that hit the far left x and y of the stage. I'm now trying a new technique by adding each of the background pieces at the far left x and y points of the preceding background piece all at once in the start of the game. Really, i'm trying to figure out the best way to tackle this sort of scenario so I want to hear from others about what they might do.

Answer (score 1):

Your basic concept will work, and to remove you just need to evaluate when the background image is off the screen :

```
if (backgroundImage.x < -backgroundImage.width)
{
    // image is no longer on the screen.
    removeChild(backgroundImage);
}
```

Comment: thanks much prototypical :) I found another way to construct my background loop, but I appreciate the code for the background image removal, I still needed that.

Comment: You should limit your questions to one issue, so that it's helpful to others. If you are too broad with your questions, like this one, it's not efficient. Situations like this only deter others from helping you. The answer to your question is that you should try your hand at a scroller and ask questions when you run into problems. The only problem you described here was handling the removal of an image gone off the screen. I answered that.